# TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=192.168.144.4:43496

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, tls1.2

I am building my network with 5 orderers, 1 org and 2 peers. Also 1 cli and 1 ca.

I scaled from 1 orderer to 5 implementing Raft. This is why I want to extend my network and do deeper tests on what happens with multiple peers.
The docker are running but I get some errors regarding TLS inside my orderer containers:

`TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=192.168.144.4:43496`

I don't understand where is the problem, because I setted up everything to implement Raft, from the crypto material to the docker compose file.

Here is the crypto-config template:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: APPLICATION_NAME.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
      - Hostname: orderer2
      - Hostname: orderer3
      - Hostname: orderer4
      - Hostname: orderer5

PeerOrgs:
  - Name: ORG_NAME
    Domain: ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true

    Template: # Number of peers 
      Count: 2

    Users:
      Count: 1
```

Here is the configtx template:

```
Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &ORG_NAME
        Name: MSP_NAME
        ID: MSP_NAME
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('MSP_NAME.admin', 'MSP_NAME.peer', 'MSP_NAME.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('MSP_NAME.admin', 'MSP_NAME.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('MSP_NAME.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME
              Port: 7051
            - Host: peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME
              Port: 8051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_4_3: true
        V1_3: false
        V1_1: false

    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
        V1_1: false

    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
        V1_3: false
        V1_2: false
        V1_1: false


Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
        - *ORG_NAME

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities


Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7050

    BatchTimeout: 500ms
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 15
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 kb

    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    Organizations:

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

    Capabilities:
            <<: *OrdererCapabilities

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities



Profiles:

    OneOrgOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *ORG_NAME
    OneOrgChannel:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *ORG_NAME

    SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                - Host: orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer2.APPLICATION_NAME.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer2.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer2.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer3.APPLICATION_NAME.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer3.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer3.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer4.APPLICATION_NAME.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer4.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer4.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer5.APPLICATION_NAME.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer5.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer5.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
            Addresses:
                - orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7050
                - orderer2.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7050
                - orderer3.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7050
                - orderer4.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7050
                - orderer5.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7050

            Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
            - <<: *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *ORG_NAME
```

And here is the docker compose:

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.ORG_NAME.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:IMAGETAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.ORG_NAME.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CERT_AUTH_PRIVATE_KEY
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.ORG_NAME.com
    networks:
      - basic

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:IMAGETAG
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info

      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=MSP_NAME
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/users/Admin@ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/msp/

      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/ca.crt

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx/
    networks:
        - basic

  orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com:
    container_name: orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:IMAGETAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer0ORG_NAME
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer1ORG_NAME
       # - ./ledgers/orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer2.APPLICATION_NAME.com:
    container_name: orderer2.APPLICATION_NAME.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:IMAGETAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer2.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer2.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer0ORG_NAME
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer1ORG_NAME
       # - ./ledgers/orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer3.APPLICATION_NAME.com:
    container_name: orderer3.APPLICATION_NAME.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:IMAGETAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer3.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer3.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer0ORG_NAME
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer1ORG_NAME
       # - ./ledgers/orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer4.APPLICATION_NAME.com:
    container_name: orderer4.APPLICATION_NAME.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:IMAGETAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 10050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer4.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer4.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer0ORG_NAME
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer1ORG_NAME
       # - ./ledgers/orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer5.APPLICATION_NAME.com:
    container_name: orderer5.APPLICATION_NAME.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:IMAGETAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 11050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer5.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/APPLICATION_NAME.com/orderers/orderer5.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer0ORG_NAME
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer1ORG_NAME
       # - ./ledgers/orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com:
    container_name: peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:IMAGETAG
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=MSP_NAME
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME_basic

      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7051

      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT="600s"
      - CORE_PEER_GRPCOPTIONS_REQUEST_TIMEOUT="600s"

      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    restart: always
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
       # - ./ledgers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/var/hyperledger/production/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    depends_on:
      - orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com
    networks:
      - basic


  peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com:
      container_name: peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com
      image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:IMAGETAG
      working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
      command: peer node start
      restart: always
      environment:
        - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
        - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com:8051
        - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
        - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
        - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
        - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
        - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=MSP_NAME
        - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/

        - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic

        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com:7051
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com:8051

        - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT="600s"
        - CORE_PEER_GRPCOPTIONS_REQUEST_TIMEOUT="600s"

        - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt

      volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
       # - ./ledgers/peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/:/var/hyperledger/production/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/peers/peer1.ORG_NAME.APPLICATION_NAME.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls

      depends_on:
        - orderer.APPLICATION_NAME.com
      ports:
        - 8051:8051
      networks:
        - basic
```

I know the docker compose is not written very well, I replacated same commands and things but at this point I would like to just let the network work and be running, next refactor and reformat code.

To run the network, I first run the generation script where the key parts are:

```
  cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
  configtxgen -profile SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -outputBlock 
./config/genesis.block
  configtxgen -profile OneOrgChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
  configtxgen -profile OneOrgChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/${MSP_NAME}anchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg $MSP_NAME
```

Next I run my network with docker compose. I get no error, everything goes up, but if I see the logs for the orderer I get the error I said. Of course if I also instantiate the cli and try to create the channel I get an error, for this reason I would like to fix this before going further.
Thanks in advance.

Just a very short log from orderer:

```
2019-11-27 08:47:24.985 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 240 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=beerchannel node=1
2019-11-27 08:47:24.985 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 241 1 [logterm: 1, index: 5] sent MsgPreVote request to 2 at term 1 channel=beerchannel node=1
2019-11-27 08:47:24.985 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 242 1 [logterm: 1, index: 5] sent MsgPreVote request to 3 at term 1 channel=beerchannel node=1
2019-11-27 08:47:24.985 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 243 1 [logterm: 1, index: 5] sent MsgPreVote request to 4 at term 1 channel=beerchannel node=1
2019-11-27 08:47:24.985 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 244 1 [logterm: 1, index: 5] sent MsgPreVote request to 5 at term 1 channel=beerchannel node=1
2019-11-27 08:47:25.095 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 245 TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=192.168.144.6:42974
2019-11-27 08:47:28.898 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 246 TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=192.168.144.7:58672
2019-11-27 08:47:30.484 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 247 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=beerchannel node=1
2019-11-27 08:47:30.485 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 248 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=beerchannel node=1
2019-11-27 08:47:30.485 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 249 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=beerchannel node=1
```

This repeats multiple times then the docker stops

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true` for both of your peers.

Comment: You are right I probably forgot it but even inserting this does not fix. The handshake is failing connecting to other orderers, not peers. Logs: http://prntscr.com/q2rpxd

Comment: Can you double check the IP addresses of all of the containers?  I might be wrong, but I'm not convinced the TLS errors are the culprit here.

Comment: They should be correct, what would the problem supposed to be with ip addresses? I mean if I inspect the orderer logs I see the error for the remote address which is 192.168.176.3:60892, I checked and in this case it is orderer2 address, but I do have errors for 192.168.176.6/20 too, which is peer0. It is clear that is a problem of communication but I don't know where to fix it

Comment: I was really looking to see the containers that mapped to the remote addresses that were associated with the errors

Comment: Can you explain better and tell me what information I need to send you?

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue before, and fixed it successfully. My solution:

- first you need to check everywhere protocol you want to call the peer or the orderer with. The correct protocol is `grpcs` not `grpc`;
- then you need to check the TLS Certificate you was using to call the peer or the orderer. Normally they are under the msp/tlscerts folder.